# Where statement with join and union does not work?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm using where statement inside my code but i did not get the right result.

```
SELECT
            t1.HistoryID
            , t1.CustomerID
            , CONVERT(VARCHAR (5), t2.hour, 108)
            , t1.Text1
            , t1.Text2
            , t1.HistoryID2
            , t1.CustomerID2
            , t1.AppointmentDate
FROM
            AppointmentGrid t1
RIGHT JOIN  Gridhour        t2 ON t1.AppointmentHour = t2.Hour
UNION
SELECT
            t1.HistoryID
            , t1.CustomerID
            , CONVERT(VARCHAR (5), t1.AppointmentHour, 108)
            , t1.Text1
            , t1.Text2
            , t1.HistoryID2
            , t1.CustomerID2
            , t1.AppointmentDate
FROM
            AppointmentGrid t1
LEFT JOIN   Gridhour        t2 ON t1.AppointmentHour = t2.Hour
WHERE
            t1.AppointmentDate = '2018-03-21';
```

I do not want to be displayed any other date except this in my example. Please look image below.

[image: MyImage]

Comment: include `WHERE t1.AppointmentDate = '2018-03-21'` in the first `SELECT`

Comment: give some explanation about your case and what you are trying to output

Comment: @Cool_Br33ze i solved my issue with this way but it doesnt work order by. I get incorrent syntax in Union

Comment: Well we can't see your code. What does it look like with the order by?

Comment: A UNION uses only one ORDER BY, so don't put an ORDER BY in the first query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error with order by mentioned in comments.
At a guess I'm thinking you need to wrap your `SELECT`, in the question, in a Derived Table and place the `ORDER BY` on the outside

```
SELECT 
    X.*
FROM
(
    SELECT
                t1.HistoryID
                , t1.CustomerID
                , [Hour] = CONVERT(VARCHAR (5), t2.hour, 108)
                , t1.Text1
                , t1.Text2
                , t1.HistoryID2
                , t1.CustomerID2
                , t1.AppointmentDate
    FROM
                AppointmentGrid t1
    RIGHT JOIN  Gridhour        t2 ON t1.AppointmentHour = t2.Hour
    WHERE
                t1.AppointmentDate = '2018-03-21'
    UNION
    SELECT
                t1.HistoryID
                , t1.CustomerID
                , [Hour] = CONVERT(VARCHAR (5), t1.AppointmentHour, 108)
                , t1.Text1
                , t1.Text2
                , t1.HistoryID2
                , t1.CustomerID2
                , t1.AppointmentDate
    FROM
                AppointmentGrid t1
    LEFT JOIN   Gridhour        t2 ON t1.AppointmentHour = t2.Hour
    WHERE
                t1.AppointmentDate = '2018-03-21'
) X
ORDER BY X.whatever_column_you_want_to_order_by
```

Comment: The where clause turns the `right join` into an `inner join` (AppointmentDate can not be null)(although I do think it is correct for OP's requirements). Also, the order by clause of a union works over the entire set, you wouldn't need to use a subquery for that. Unless, of course you need to sort within the two sets.

Comment: @HoneyBadger Agree. I took a guess at OP's requirements based on OP's comments